# Azure Search - Highlights from HTML returns strange text

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search to index lots of HTML files in blob storage. The "highlights" field that comes back is pretty nasty - lots of stuff like this: [image: ]Loadmore

Is there a recommended way to pull out highlights from search results that are more friendly to the end user?

Comment: Are regular expressions an option? You could strip out non-alpha/numeric characters before the [image] if that's what you're after.

Comment: My problem is that the text is really just kinda nasty.  Right now Azure Search is doing the indexing all the HTML.  I'm considering taking all the inner text and alt text out of the HTML document myself and allowing the service to index that - but that seems counter-intuitive...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "highlightPreTag" and "highlightPostTag" - learn more here [Search Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents). 
Could you edit your question to provide more details about the request and the response?